# Custom UITableViewCell height changes when moved

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, cell

I am using Autolayout and `estimatedHeightForRowAt`to dynamically change cell height. This is the code I am using:

```
var heightAtIndexPath = NSMutableDictionary()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = self.heightAtIndexPath.object(forKey: indexPath)
    if ((height) != nil) {
        return CGFloat(height as! CGFloat)
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let height = cell.frame.size.height
    self.heightAtIndexPath.setObject(height, forKey: indexPath as NSCopying)
}
```

In `viewDidLoad()`

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.reloadData()
```

Now when I do a swipe right to 'complete a task', the `priorityNumber`on which the data is sorted becomes 0 for that particular cell and the cell moves to the bottom of the list. I am using `NSFetchedResultsController` changeType `.move` to move the cell to the bottom automatically when the coreData is changed.

The issue is that the cell changes it's height a bit when moved. It's random - sometimes it changes when it goes to the '0th' position and sometimes it changes when it goes back to it's original position.

It doesn't happen always, but sometimes. Any idea what maybe the issue. Here is the autolayout constraints for the contents in the custom cell:

```
textview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 48).isActive = true
    textview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor,  constant: 6).isActive = true
    textview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    textview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scheduledSign.topAnchor, constant: -2).isActive = true
   // textview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: line.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

    _ = scheduledSign.anchor(nil, left: contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: line.topAnchor, right: contentView.rightAnchor, topConstant: 2, leftConstant: 54, bottomConstant: 4, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    line.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 48).isActive = true
    line.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    line.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
   // line.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textview.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    line.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0.5).isActive = true

   _ = prioritycircle.anchor(self.contentView.topAnchor, left: self.contentView.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: nil, topConstant: 20, leftConstant: 16, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 8, widthConstant: 20  , heightConstant: 20)
```

Here is a video of this issue: https://youtu.be/ecU3_ticw3g

Please help! Thanks.

This is my `cellforrowatindexPath`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellid, for: indexPath) as! TasksTableViewCell

    cell.textview.text = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).sNote
    cell.prioritycircle.backgroundColor = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).sPriorityColor
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    cell.backgroundColor = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).cellbackgroundColor
    cell.textview.backgroundColor = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).cellbackgroundColor
    cell.belliconview.tintColor = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).belliconcolor
   // cell.scheduledSign.backgroundColor = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).cellbackgroundColor
    if (fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).sTaskCompleted)
    {
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    }
    else{
        cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    if (fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).sReminderState) {

        cell.belliconview.tintColor = (fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).belliconcolor)
        //cell.scheduledSign.text = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).sReminderDate
    } else {
        cell.belliconview.tintColor = (fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath).belliconcolor) 
    }

    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    return cell
}
```

and this is where I am reloading my tableview after content change in FRC:

```
 func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {

    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
    case .move:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)

    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)

    default:
        return

    }
}
```

Comment: Solvable issue only. Can u show ur cellForRowAtIndexPath code? and, where u r reloading the tableview with the help of NSFetchResultController

Comment: @McDonal_11 Just updated my post with the relevant code. Please take a look.

Comment: I wil chk and let u

Comment: I have used UILabel. try this way.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Logic. Try to use `UILabel` instead of `UITextView` once.

Add UILabel in UITableViewCell (Row height = 44) . Give constraints, "5,5,5,5" and height as "34". `Number of lines` as Zero. In `Size Inspector`, Give `horizontal` and `vertical` as `1000` & `1000` respectively for both `Content Hugging Property` and `Content Compression Resistance Priority`.

Click, UILabel's Height Constraints, in `Size Inspector`, Change its `Priority` to 750.

```
let getValuesInString = ["abc\nLets meet today\nyes. sure", "123", "qwerty\n12345\nASDD\n123"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return getValuesInString.count 
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! SampleTableViewCell
        cell.testLbl.text = getValuesInString[indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return cell
    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension 

}
```

**Storyboard Constraints**

[image]

Comment: Will try this thanks. Any idea how to do above things without storyboard. Specifically, content hugging and priority etc?

Comment: Without storyboard, U have to get each and every row heights in NSDictionary. After that you have to reload tableview. Else, there will change in Height. Reason is, Cell is reusing each and every time.

Comment: Well I have done the whole project without using storyboard and there is no way to get back to it. What should I do now?

Comment: Storyboard is best. If u r gng to do in storyboard from first, it wil take 1hr. thats it.

Comment: Else, U have to calculate height and store in NSDictionary, then from that U have to do in heightForRowAtIndexPath. Not, in estimatedHeightForRowAt.

Comment: Before that, delete that estimatedHeightForRowAt, and copy that code to heightForRowAtIndexPath. Try once.

Comment: Can you write a demo code for this NSDictionary bit? Will help me out thanks a lot!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164108/discussion-between-mcdonal-11-and-osama-naeem).

Comment: I tried this using storyboards today and still no difference. The cell height changes when it is moved. This method is not working.

Comment: Can u mail ur proj?