# Cant get full text in label in .xib Swift

Tags: swift, storyboard, xib

[image: Shortened label]

[image: Autolayout constraints]

I can show other info if needed.

Comment: Did you set `numberOfLines` to `0`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48479246/custom-uitableviewcell-height-changes-when-moved/48504877#48504877 you can get answer here. How to set dynamic height for UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough space for full text. Set number of lines of label to 0 (label height now will be as big as is needed)

[image]

Comment: look down please